# Почему не получается эффект blur в css?

Tags: html, css, css3

Blur также захватывает и текст, но почему, если используется свойство z-index? Или я просто что-то не так делаю?

```css
.blur {
  background-image: url('http://paranormal-news.ru/_nw/88/47028101.jpg');
  height:500px;
  width:100%;
  filter:blur(5px);
  z-index:1;
}
.text {
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:-70px;
  color:red;
  font-size:3em;
  z-index:9999;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
    <p>
    Какой-то очень важный текст!
  </p>
</div>
<div class="blur"></div>
```

Comment: Выставлять 9999 z-индексу - плохая практика. Советую почитать, что он делает, чем думать по типу "ставлю 9999 - передний план".

Comment: Это указано исключительно для примера или по типу "чтоб наверняка". Но совет полезный, почитать действительно стоит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Без `position:relative` `z-index` не будет работать

```css
.blur {
  background-image: url('http://paranormal-news.ru/_nw/88/47028101.jpg');
  height:500px;
  width:100%;
  filter:blur(5px);
  z-index:1; 
}
.text {
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:-70px;
  color:red;
  font-size:3em;
  z-index:9999; 
  position:relative
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
    <p>
    Какой-то очень важный текст!
  </p>
</div>
<div class="blur"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогли!)

Comment: Наш сайт отличается от социальных сетей. Он помогает решать прикладные задачи. Поэтому мы используем комментарии только по делу — уточнить проблему, дать конструктивную критику или добавить полезную информацию.

Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.

http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

```css
.blur {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('http://paranormal-news.ru/_nw/88/47028101.jpg');
  height:500px;
  width:100%;
  filter:blur(5px);
  z-index:99;
}
.text {
 position: relative;
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:-70px;
  color:red;
  font-size:3em;
  z-index:9999;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
    <p>
    Какой-то очень важный текст!
  </p>
</div>
<div class="blur"></div>
```